# Earthing circuit ground

Tags: grounding

what is the benefit of connecting DC ground terminal to the Earth in  AC to DC converter?

Comment: If you want the floating feature you simply don't ground. You ground it for safety and/or to have a common ground with some other equipment if required.

Comment: i just want to know the benefit as stated in the questions , so all of that is just a protection from being shocked if  the line wire touch the ground

Comment: "in some circuits": This is too broad. In engineering, we do things to achieve a certain goal. I'd recommend picking *one* example, and asking why. Maybe you can research reasons for that one purpose and discuss these already in your question? Until you do that, I think the appropriate reaction to your question for now is considering it too broad to be answerable.

Comment: @MarcusMüller i edited the question

Comment: You broadened it even further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the common reasons is to reduce output common mode noise. On an unearthed SMPS, the primary winding is capacitively coupled to the secondary winding by several hundred pF in some cases and this means that although the DC differential voltage might be pure DC with low ripple, both DC terminals can have significant common-mode noise from the primary.

Earthing one leg of the DC output can dramatically reduce this effect. When an SMPS is used that doesn't require an earth, what is normally done to remove output common-mode switching noise is to use a Y rated capacitor of about 1 nF between the output winding and the rectified DC bus on the primary however, it isn't as effective as earthing the DC output.